# Checking html5 pattern regex in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I have the below code in HTML5 for validating some names

```
<input name="desiredNames" type="text" placeholder="your-site-name" pattern="[a-z0-9\-\.]{3,25}" id="desiredNames">
```

It works, but I want to add to it an extra checking feature using regex, as follow:
1. the name is not allowed to start with sign period . or sign minus -
2.the name is not allowed to end with sign period . or sign minus -

I don't know how to use ^, $, ? to make these happened. ( I tried a few examples seen in the forums)
Also to that html code I have the below js code

```
(function checkName() {

let wantedNames = document.getElementById('desiredNames');
let form = document.getElementById('form');
let elem = document.createElement('div');
        elem.id = 'notify';
        elem.style.display = 'none';

        form.appendChild(elem);

wantedNames.addEventListener('invalid', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    if ( ! event.target.validity.valid ) {
        wantedNames.className    = 'invalid animated shake';
        elem.textContent   = 'Name can contains small letters, numbers, dot . and minus -,but not at the beginning or at the end, ie escu.ionel-74';
        elem.className     = 'error';
        elem.style.display = 'block';
    }
});

wantedNames.addEventListener('input', function(event){
    if ( 'block' === elem.style.display ) {
        wantedNames.className = '';
        elem.style.display = 'none';
    }
});
```

})();

Any tips and some good resources for regex patterns?

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably looking for this:

```
^[^.-].{1,23}[^.-]$
```

`^` means starting at the beginning of string, except when inside `[]` which means `not`

`.` means any character except newline, but inside `[]` means period

`-` is generally used as a range inside `[]` (`A-z`) except when it is placed at the end where it just means the minus sign.

Probably a better explainer:

https://regex101.com/r/OYRnMO/1

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of ways to achieve that, but the shortest would be to add `\b` word boundaries on both ends to require word chars at the start and end of the input. Note you do not need to use `^` (start of string) and `$` (end of string) anchors, because they are added automatically by the HTML5 engine when compiling the regex from the pattern.

So, you may use

```
pattern="\b[a-z0-9.-]{3,25}\b"
```

and it will be parsed as `/^(?:\b[a-z0-9.-]{3,25}\b)$/` matching 3 to 25 lowercase ASCII letters (add `A-Z` after `[` to also match uppercase ASCII letters), digits, `.` or `-`, but no `.` or `-` will be allowed at the start and end of the string.

See the demo:

```css
input:valid {
  color: black;
}
input:invalid {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<input name="desiredNames" type="text" placeholder="your-site-name" pattern="\b[a-z0-9.-]{3,25}\b" id="desiredNames" />
```

Comment: Thx. It works. I think I will take some spare time to read more about regex in html5 pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You will try below option.

"
<input  required  pattern="[A-Za-z0-9]+[\.\-]*[A-Za-z0-9]+" maxlength=25 minlength=3  name="desiredNames" type="text" placeholder="your-site-name" id="desiredNames" >
"

it's working for me.

Comment: Thx a lot. It works for me, too. I am not using A-Z, just small ones.